# How can I restrict duplicate primary key in laravel model?

Tags: laravel, primary-key

I am working on a laravel project in which I have set a custom primary key. However, the project allows two different entries to have the same value in the field set as primary key. How do I restrict this?

I have set the public $incrementing property on my model to false and also set the protected $keyType property to string.

```
class Students extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'reg_no';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

I expected that the code will raise an error if I enter two records will the same value in the 'reg_no' field, which is defined as primary, but the record is being saved without an error.

Comment: Can you add the migration for your `students` table?

Comment: It is in your migration declaration that you enforce primary key constraint.

Comment: Adding the unique constraint in my migration worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it to unique in your migration

```
Schema::table('students', function($table)
{
    $table->string('reg_no')->unique(); 
});
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: Isn't unique constraint difference from primary key?

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin any unique index can be a primary key. Codd Rules

Answer (score 2):

Can't guess why you change primary key like that but you can:

- Set the column as unique in migration.
- use a unique validation rule to prevent duplicate entry.